# Temp directory for all users?

Tags: windows-7, windows

This is the Temp directory for my user account:

```
C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Is there a Temp directory that is accessible by all users?

Comment: There is not a shared temporal folder for all users

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a temp directory in the Windows directory, i.e., `%SYSTEMROOT%\Temp`, but its use is deprecated. Applications should use the user-specific temp directories.

You can, however, redirect users' temp directories, so you could have them all point to the same directory, if that's what you are after. You would just change their `TMP` and `TEMP` environment variables to point wherever you want. Ensure that all of the affected users can write to this new directory.

Comment: Redirecting temp for all users to a single folder is not a good idea. Some applications write temp stuff related to a particular user in temp. This can lead to multiple instances of same application for different users overwriting the files.

Comment: *Can* do something and *should* do something are two different things. :)

Comment: @GaneshR., Actually it is a very good idea. Windows puts over 300Mb files in temp folder for each user just in a week. if you are a system admin and have to clean temp folder in 20 computers every day, you have to multiply number of folders you need to clean by number of users.

Answer (score 2):

Not a *Temp* directory per se, but you could use `%PUBLIC%` AKA `C:\Users\Public` as a workaround.

Also, `C:\Users\All Users` seems to be accessible to all users on the machine.

from [a quick search](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/what-public-folder-how-use-it):

> The Public folder is located in "C:\Users\Public", in all Windows
>   versions. All user accounts registered in Windows have access to it.
>   That's why it is named Public. Any file and folder found in
>   "C:\Users\Public" is completely accessible to all users

Comment: Actually no. The question is *"Is there a Temp directory that is accessible by all users?"*, so you *cannot* answer yes to that. Using the `Public` folder is a *possibly* useful work-around, but **it is not a Temp directory**.

Comment: @robinCTS I see

Comment: I would suggest you edit your answer and add something like "No, you cannot. However as a possible work-around you could …"

Comment: @robinCTS: This just screams "C:\Users\All Users\AppData\Local\Temp"

Answer (score 0):

(I am using `powershell` here!)

## workaround 1

One can create a **temp folder in the publicly shared folder** like this:

```powershell
## "$tmp":         thus you can use $tmp later on to reference it
## "-force":       does not complain if already existing
## " | out-null":  suppresses md standard output
PS C:\> $tmp = "$env:public\tmp" ; md -force $tmp | out-null
```

It should be accessable by all users.

However the shared folder [**may be read-only** if configured explicitely](https://www.howtogeek.com/189508/how-to-share-files-between-user-accounts-on-windows-linux-or-os-x/).

## workaround 2

Using **`$env:windir\Temp` or `$env:systemroot\Temp`** (e.g. `C:\Windows\Temp`) [**seems deprecated and uglier**](https://www.howtogeek.com/189508/how-to-share-files-between-user-accounts-on-windows-linux-or-os-x/), but works (e.g. in a *Win2012R2* environment) with some extra adjustments...

You can't list its direct content, which may not be bad, depending on your needs:

```powershell
PS C:\> cd $env:windir\temp
PS C:\Windows\Temp> ls
ls : Der Zugriff auf den Pfad "C:\Windows\temp" wurde verweigert.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ ls
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\temp:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
PS C:\Windows\Temp> md test ; echo "test123" > test\test.txt

Verzeichnis: C:\Windows\temp\test


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       28.09.2018     17:08             20 test.txt
```

But other users won't be able to see it normally, if they do not have admin rights:

```powershell
## as other non-admin user:
PS C:\Windows\Temp> cd test
cd : Zugriff verweigert
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ cd test
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\Temp\test:String) [Set-Location], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

cd : Der Pfad "C:\Windows\Temp\test" kann nicht gefunden werden, da er nicht vorhanden ist.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ cd test
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Windows\Temp\test:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

To solve this one may want to additionally [**change permissions via `Set-Acl`**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johan/2008/10/01/powershell-editing-permissions-on-a-file-or-folder/)